# AngularJS listen to state change event

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a, hopefully, simple question. I've built a small App with Ionic and AngularJS. There are two States, one of them is a tab containing a form. When submitted the form tab shouldn't be accessible anymore. I've tried to write a boolean variable in local storage and it works fine for me. Unfortunately when I submit the form I can still push the back button of ionic or the android hardwarebutton to go back to the form and submit again. I called a function via ng-init that switches the state before loading but this only works with refreshing the page, not at the state change.

How can I listen to a state change? Do you have a better solution?

Comment: you can listen to `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart')`, `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess')` and `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError')`

Answer (score 13):

It's quite easy actually, UI-router give you access to 3 differents state listener :

`$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',myFunc)` -> fires when state is changing

`$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', myFunc)` -> fires when state has changed successfully

`$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', myFunc)` -> fires when state change has failed

Then you can disallow the access to one page using the resolve attribute of your state by associating it to a promise. [see doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

If the promise is resolved, access is granted else access is denied.

Comment: NOTE: State change events are deprecated, DISABLED and replaced by Transition Hooks as of version 1.0 - https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events